# Dealing with blanks in a Search formula

Tags: excel

Hi guys having a bit of a problem with the below formula,

What it is intended to do is search a customers email address to see if the customer name is contained in the domain of said email address, the name is split into three parts as seen in the formula below.

My problem is when one of the customer name cells is blank the formula evaluates as true (E-mail address okay), I've tried using ISBLANK but I can't get it to function properly that code is also displayed below.

```
=IF(G4="","No E-mail Address",IF(L4&K4&J4="","No Customer name on file",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&J4,G4)),"E-mail Address OK",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&K4,G4)),"E-mail Address OK",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&L4,$G4)),"Email Address okay",("E-mail Address NOT OK"))))))


=IF(G4="","No E-mail Address",IF(L4&K4&J4="","No Customer name on file",IF(ISBLANK*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&J4,G4))),"E-mail Address OK",IF(ISBLANK(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&K4,G4))),"E-mail Address OK",IF(ISBLANK(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&L4,$G4))),"Email address okay",("E-mail Address NOT OK"))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula evaluates to true because ISBLANK is set as a positive condition.  You'll need to change it to `NOT(ISBLANK...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version - it checks all three name cells in one go and the added `(J4:L4<>"")` [range not blank] part stops you getting "false positives"

`=IF(G4="","No E-mail Address",IF(L4&K4&J4="","No Customer name on file",IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH("@"&J4:L4,G4)/(J4:L4<>""))),"(Email address NOT OK)","Email address okay")))`

Comment: I've plugged it into my worksheet and indeed blanks no longer evaluate as true but correct inputs no longer produce a "Email Address okay". In fact I can't get the formula to evaluate to "Email address okay" regardless of the inputs.

Comment: I made a small edit to the formula shortly after I posted it - the "lookup value" is now 2^15 rather than just 2 - that's required to make it work correctly - are you using the updated version?